# How do I perform an unsigned right shift (>>> in Java) in C/C++?

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation

How do I perform an unsigned right shift (>>> in Java) in C/C++?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`>>>` is unsigned right shift, so I would think that in C this would be the same as

```
unsigned int foo;
unsigned int bar = foo >> whatever;
```

Answer (score 38):

In C, to get an unsigned shift, you just do a shift on an unsigned type.

```
unsigned int result = (unsigned int)valueToBeShifted >> shiftAmount;
```

Note that there is no guarantee that `>>` on a signed type gives you a signed shift in C -- this is implementation defined behavior.  Most common implementations produce a signed shift if the type is signed, however.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ doing a right shift on an unsigned value has identical behavior to doing a right shift on a signed value. If the MSB is set, then >> will shift in a 1.

```
unsigned int myInt = 0x80000000;
myInt >>= 1;
```

The result stored in myInt will be 0xC0000000

However, if the MSB is not set, a right shift on an unsigned value will work as it should.

```
unsigned int myInt = 0x40000000;
myInt >>= 1;
```

The result will be 0x20000000

So in order to get the desired behavior in C++, you could:

1. Do a single shift, zero out the MSB, then do the remainder of the shifts.
2. Right shift N bits, and zero out the top N bits.

Comment: That's not true... Left shift of unsigned and signed integers have identical behavior in C/C++, but right shift of unsigned and signed integers don't have.