# What does this ">>=" operator mean in C?

Tags: c

```
unsigned long set;
/*set is after modified*/
set >>= 1;
```

I found this in a kernel system call but I don't understand, how does it work?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The expression `set >>= 1;` means `set = set >> 1;` that is right shift bits of `set` by `1` (self assigned form of `>>` bitwise right shift operator check [Bitwise Shift Operators](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205204519/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed(v=vs.80).aspx)).

Suppose if `set` is:

```
BIT NUMBER    31   n=27        m=17                 0
              ▼    ▼           ▼                    ▼
set =         0000 1111 1111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Then after `set >> = 1;` variable `set` becomes:

```
BIT NUMBER    31   n=26        m=16                 0
              ▼     ▼           ▼                   ▼
set =         0000 0111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Notice the bits number shifted.

Note a interesting point: Because `set` is `unsigned long` so this `>>` operation should be [logical shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)( [unsigned shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429479/how-do-i-perform-an-unsigned-right-shift-in-java-in-c-c)) a logical shift does not preserve a number's sign bit.

Additionally,  because you are shifting all bits to right (towards lower significant number) so one right shift is = divide number by two.

[check this code](http://codepad.org/XtD7IYyI) (just to demonstrate last point):

```
int main(){
 unsigned long set = 268304384UL;
 set >>= 1;
 printf(" set :%lu \n", set);
 set = 268304384UL;
 set /= 2;
 printf(" set :%lu \n", set);
 return 1; 
}
```

And output:

```
 set :134152192 
 set :134152192
```

(note: its doesn't means `>>` and `/` are both same)

Similarly you have operator `<<=` for left shift, check other available [Bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Bitwise_operators) and [Compound assignment operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Compound_assignment_operators), also check section: [bit expressions](https://web.archive.org/web/20200224083023/http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/) and difference between: [signed/arithmetic shift and unsigned shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift).

Answer (score 17):

This "right-shift"s the value by one bit. If you move all the bits of an integer to the right by 1 then you effectively "divide by 2" because binary is a base-2 numbering system.

Imagine you have the number 12 in binary:

```
1100 = 12 in binary
 110 =  6 in binary (1100 right-shifted)
```

Just like if you moved all of the digits in a base-10 number right by one you would be dividing by 10.

Answer (score 6):

Every binary operator can be combined with `=`. In all cases

```
dest op= expression
```

is equivalent to

```
dest = dest op expression
```

(except if `dest` has any side effects, they only take place once).

So this means that

```
set>>=1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
set = set >> 1;
```

Since `>>` is the binary right-shift operator, it means to shift the value in `set` right by 1 bit.

Answer (score 4):

This shifts bit to the right by 1 which is equivalent to division by 2. For more information on bit shifting, refer to [Bitwise Shift Operators (C)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205204519/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The above command performs right shift by one bit .Refer bit wise operations in c from this link http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html