# How will this program get executed?

Tags: c

How will this program get executed?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() { 
    char a = 0xAA;
    int b;
    b = (int) a;
    printf("%d\n", a); 
    b = b >> 4;
    printf("%x", b); 
}
```

**[Question]**

I have problem in statement `b = (int)a`. Can you give the binary representation of `b` when `a` is stored in it?

Comment: Which part are you wondering about?

Comment: I think you need to know about [`>>` operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769948/what-does-this-operator-mean-in-c/17769959#17769959) and `a = 0xAA` == `10101010` in binary

Comment: Why not just [run it yourself and see](http://ideone.com/zaBjWo) ?

Comment: I think you wants to know how this code work, **?**

Comment: i have problem in statement b=(int)a.
ca you give me the binary form in which it will get stored in b?

Comment: @user2714916 edit and explain clearly what you wants in question. its typecasting

Comment: @PaulR What he wants different? he has some doubts in code

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i have problem in statement b=(int)a. ca you give me the binary form in which it will get stored in b?

Comment: @user2714916 not `a`'s binary represent is `10101010` in this MSB is set so negative number its value is `-86`. This value remain same in `b` int `-86` because `b` is a int probably in `4` bytes in your system then its should `be = ffffffaa` int binary `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 1010`

Comment: @user2714916 Your question is not bad (really good question) but presentation is not good. Please take time to post and ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the statement `b = (int)a;`, we are typecasting a `char` to an `int`. Assuming that `char` is implicitly signed (NB: not always true!) and that `int` is 32 bits, then the `char` value `0xAA` gets widened with sign extension, so `0xAA` becomes `0xFFFFFFAA` which is equivalent to `-86` in decimal.

Comment: @Grijesh: There's no UB in the cast. If you mean here: `b = b >> 4;` then that's *implementation-defined* behaviour, not undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Parul yes I realized so I deleted my comment Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
char a = 0xAA; // line 1
int b; // line 2
b = (int) a; // line 3
printf("%d\n", a); // line 4
b = b >> 4; // line 5
printf("%x", b); // line 6
```

Line 1: assigned a character to variable `a` of `char` type from hexadecimal

Line 2: declaring a variable `b` of `int` type

Line 3: Assign value of `char a` by typecasting to from `char` to `int`. It will output a int value.

Line 4: outputs the value of `char` a in int format

Line 5: reassign value of b by right shifting it to 4.

Line 6: Output value of b in hexadecimal format. So output should be in something e.g.; FFAA454 like.

This is how your code is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what the console will output, here is what I get:

```
-86
fffffffa
```

In the future if you want to see how a test case is executed try using something like [this](http://ideone.com/DSmIat).