# What does hibyte = Value >> 8 meaning?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am using C for developing my program and I found out from an example code

```
unHiByte = unVal >> 8;
```

What does this mean? If `unVal = 250`. What could be the value for `unHiByte`?

Comment: [Shift Operators: >> and <<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx)

Comment: Read [What does this “>>=” operator mean in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769948/what-does-this-operator-mean-inc/17769959#17769959)

Comment: Why not simply try it out for yourself?

Comment: i think the OP is confused with the why i.e. the high level intention of using bit shifts. +1 for that possibility

Answer (score 5):

`>>` in programming is a bitwise operation. The operation `>>` means shift right operation.

So `unVal >> 8` means shift right `unVal` by 8 bits. Shifting the bits to the right can be interpreted as dividing the value by 2.

Hence, `unHiByte = unval >> 8` means `unHiByte = unVal/(2^8)` (divide `unVal` by 2 eight times)

Comment: Slight clarification >> 1 means dividing by 2 once. First part of answer makes it look like >> 8 means dividing by 2 once. +1

Comment: @fayyazkl sorry about that, maybe its just my bad way of explaining. haha

Comment: @LekshmiGopikrishnan no prob! :) accept the answer if its what you want please. :)

Comment: @CodingBird By no means that is a problem. We all just collaborate to help each other. The concept is right. I just suggested a wording improvement with a possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the shift operator itself (since that is answered already), here the assumption is that unVal is a two byte variable with a high byte (the upper 8 bits) and a low byte (the lower 8 bits). The intent is to obtain the value produced by ONLY the upper 8 bits and discarding the lower bits.

The shift operator though should easily be learned via any book / tutorial and perhaps was the reason some one down voted the question.

Comment: OK so unHiByte = unVal << 8; means retrieving only the lower 8 bits from unVal?? Please make that too clear for me.

Comment: Not exactly. The concept is right though. But the problem is when you shift some thing left, it appends 8 zeros in the lower byte and promote the lower byte to higher one. To obtain lower bits only, & it will a mask with only right most 8 bits as 1 i.e. unVal & 255.

Answer (score 0):

[The `>>` is a bitwise right shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed.aspx).

It operates on bits. With `unHiByte = unVal >> 8;` When `unVal=250`.

[Its binary form is `11111010`](http://acc6.its.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~gurwitz/core5/nav2tool.html)

Right shift means to shift the bits to the right. So when you shift `1111 1010`, 8 digits to right you get `0000 0000`.

**Note:** You can easily determine the right shift operation result by dividing the number to the left of `>>` by 2^(number to right of `>>`)

So, `250/2`<sup>8</sup>`= 0`

Answer (score -1):

For example: if you have a hex `0x2A63` and you want to take `2A` or you want to take `63` out of it, then you will do this.

For example, if we convert `2A63` to binary which is: `0010101001100011`. (that is 16 bits, first 8 bits are `2A` and the second 8 bits are `63`)

The issue is that binary always starts from right. So we have to push the first 8 bits (`2A`) to the right side to be able to get it.

```
uint16_t hex = 0x2A63;
uint8_t part2A = (uint8_t)(hex >> 8) // Pushed the first
// eight bits (2A) to right and (63) is gone out of the way. Now we have 0000000000101010 
// Now Line 2 returns for us 0x2A which the last 8 bits (2A).

// To get 63 we will do simply: 
uint8_t part63 = (uint8_t)hex; // As by default the 63 is on the right most side in the binary.
```

It is that simple.