# Python >>= help for decimal to binary function

Tags: python

Hello I was writing a decimal to binary function and I found this code that works perfectly:

```
while n > 0:
    b = str(n % 2) + b
    n >>= 1
```

However I do not know what `>>=` does could you enlighten me?

Many thanks

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: Read [What does this “>>=” operator mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769948/what-does-this-operator-mean-in-c/17769959#17769959)

Answer (score 2):

It's a binary right shift operation. The bits in `n` are shifted to the right by 1. It's equivalent of saying `n = n >> 1`.

From [BitwiseOperators in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> `x >> y`:
>   Returns `x` with the bits shifted to the right by `y` places. This is the same as `//`'ing `x` by `2**y`.

For instance, assume an integer `4` and let's shift it to the right by `1` places.

```
 # First let's look at what 4 is in binary.
 >>> bin(4)[2:].zfill(8) # this pads to 8 bits.
 '00000100'

 # If you shift all the bits towards the right 1 places the result is
 # '00000010', which in turn is 2 in base 10.
 >>> 4 >> 1
 2

 >>> bin(2)[2:].zfill(8)
 '00000010'
```

Answer (score 1):

it's right shift operation. One bit right is equivalent to divide by 2.

Comment: indeed purpose here of >>= is divide by 2