# Operator >>= meaning in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I know `>>` is Binary Right Shift Operator but what does `>>=` mean, like if I want Log2 on `x` I need `while(x >>= 1) result++;`.

Comment: You could always try it out yourself...

Comment: `x >>= 1` is the short for `x = x >> 1;`

Comment: This question was already asked, here is the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17769959/4811236

Comment: There's nothing particularly interesting about this operator. If you want to think about something funky, consider `while( x --> 0 )`.

Comment: wow.. you're bad people... @Olaf you can't search > in google. 
-paxdiablo I didn't see it. 
-Cool_Guy  thanks.
thanks everybody for the hate.

Comment: @CoolGuy: It is not (exactly). The operand is only evaluated once, thus e.g. side-effects are only generated once, while for the assignment they would be twice.

Comment: @Olaf Didn't knew that! Thanks! Is it the same for all shorthand operators like `-=`, `+=`, `*=` etc?

Comment: @CoolGuy: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: @Olaf Umm. Could you tell me which section is it mentioned in?

Comment: @CoolGuy: If your browser doesn't have a search-function, why not start with "assignment operators"? (giving a man a fish vs. teach him fishing ...)

Comment: @Olaf Thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the bitwise shift right assignment operator; `x >>= 1` is equivalent to `x = x >> 1`.

(It has the same precedence as assignment `=`).